# string to XML Android

Tags: android, xml, listadapter

I have a XML string comming from a Rest WS that I created on .net, I am able to consume the websevice and get the return I need, however this returns comes back as String.

XML from WS:

```
<Example>
  <Name> Carlos </name>
  <ID> 1 </ID>
</Example>
```

Once retrieved in Java, it looks like this:

```
 String response = "<Example> <Name> Carlos </name> <ID> 1 </ID> </Example>"
```

My idea is to parse this back to XML so I can work with it, I already have a handler class that would take these values, but I cant figure out how to parse it.

My idea is to populate a list adapter with this information since it would return many Names and IDs on a single query.

Thanks

Comment: IMHO you're confusing file format (XML) with data object that contains it (String). Your String `response` is already an XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is to parse this back to XML

I think you mean you want to create some kind of Structure containing those strings.

You have options of using the Pull Parser, SAX Parser or DOM based parser

I suggest you use the lightweight [SAX parser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser) for this